# Mysql query stuck in sending data

Tags: mysql, database

my query is taking long time to process ans remains in "sending data".

```
SELECT items.defindex,items.name,items.image_url,price.median as price,user_items.id ,user_items.item_id,user_items.original_id
    FROM user_items
    INNER JOIN  items ON user_items.defindex=items.defindex
    LEFT JOIN price ON user_items.defindex=price.defindex && user_items.quality=price.quality
    WHERE user_items.user_id=6 && user_items.flag_cannot_trade=0 && price.price>=0 && items.price<=40 && items.banned=0 
    ORDER by price.median desc
```

and below is the explain output

[image]

Index of all three tables
[image]
Ill provide more info if requested

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are missing indexes, run `show indexes on table_name` for all the 3 tables and share them into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK from the available indexes its clear that you are missing indexes which would be needed when you deal with large data

Your tables are joined with the column `defindex` and its only indexed in `price`

So first thing add indexes on other two tables.

```
alter table items add index defindex_idx(defindex);
alter table user_items add index defindex_idx(defindex);
```

Now you have `where condition` and `order by` , for optimizer to scan less number of rows you need to add more indexes.

```
alter table user_items add index uid_flag_idx(user_id,flag_cannot_trade);
alter table price add index price_idx(price);
alter table items add index price_idx(price);
alter table items add index banned_idx(banned);
alter table price add index median_idx(median);
```

Make sure to take a backup of the table before applying the indexes.

And also try `price.median` in the selection part.

Answer (score 1):

Create indexes for all this fields:

```
user_items.defindex
items.defindex
user_items.defindex
price.defindex
user_items.quality
price.quality
user_items.user_id
user_items.flag_cannot_trade
price.price
items.price
items.banned
price.median
```